# Tracking MKMapView's centerCoordinate

Tags: ios, mkmapview, tracking, key-value-observing

I need to accurately track the `centerCoordinate` of an `MKMapView` while the user zooms/pans the map, i.e. between the `regionWillChangeAnimated:` and `regionDidChangeAnimated:` events.

I've tested the following approaches by trying to lock an `MKAnnotation` to the map's center. Unfortunately, none of them work well enough:

- Using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005597/uipangesturerecognizer-on-mkmapview)): this works quite well while the display is touched, but doesn't update while the map is animated after the touch gesture is complete. In addition, the updates lag behind the actual `centerCoordinate`.
- Using `UIScrollViewDelegate` I [subclassed MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636868/is-there-way-to-limit-mkmapview-maximum-zoom-level) to receive the `scrollViewDidScroll:` event. This worked, but the event isn't triggered on every scrolling increment, leading to jerky updates.
- Using **KVO Notifications**: following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473706/how-do-i-zoom-an-mkmapview-to-the-users-current-location-without-cllocationmanag) pattern, I tried to observe the mapview's `centerCoordinate`. It works for the `userLocation`, but the notifications don't seem to be sent for `centerCoordinate`.

Any ideas on how to track `centerCoordinate` effectively and accurately?

KVO seemed like the best bet. Is there a trick to making it work with `MKMapView`'s `centerCoordinate` property?

Comment: Did you ever solve this via KVO Notifications?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you are trying to have something (annotation in your case) that is always in the centre of the screen, right? 
Not sure what this annotation is used for, but is it acceptable to place another transparent view on top of the map that acts as annotation (you can also make this view be same size as the map and have subview of it act as annotation). It'll have the same effect on the user. Than in the region did change, you can get the centerCoordinate and do whatever processing you need to do. I don't think you need to do any processing as the user pans or pinches the map... Not to mention that annotations are meant to have fixed coordinate.