# get MKMapView callbacks as map is being dragged by user?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

With IOS MapKit, how can one get callbacks during the dragging of the map itself?   I know I can detect the begin and end of a drag, however I want to get callbacks during the drag.  As such I'm after a stream of callbacks as the user begins to drag, then a break when they still have their finger down and have not released, then more callbacks as they keep dragging again.

Background:  Want a trigger to update the centre lat/long of the current map as the user moves the map.  Not sure how the rate of updates for my requirements would be controlled, however perhaps if there is a callback function I am not aware of it will be configurable?

Backup Question: If this is not possible out of the box with MKMapView then how would you best recommend I cover my requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need implement MKMapViewDelegate methods for example

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
```

or add your panGesture to map

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* panRec = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didDragMap:)]; 
panRec.delegate = self; 
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:panRec];
```

and need implement pan delegate method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {   
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and they only fire when you start to drag, and when you finish dragging.  Not in between   :(

Comment: You can add panGesture to map `UIPanGestureRecognizer* panRec = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didDragMap:)]; panRec.delegate = self; [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:panRec];`

Comment: ok thanks - there's no existing delegate call then is there?   If you want to update your answer with the UIPanGestureRecognizer approach I can select

Comment: had to unselect for the moment - doesn't seem to be this straight forward - I did see some notes here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005597/uipangesturerecognizer-on-mkmapview, and use shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer but no luck yet

Comment: ok - got it - so you need (as the previous link mentioned) to add this into the mix:  extension GcMapView : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
}

Comment: Yeah I agree with you